# Finding all polynomials $P(x)$ satisfying $(P(x)+P(\frac{1}{x}))^2 =P(x^2)P(\frac{1}{x^2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Find all polynomials $P(x)$ satisfying
> $$\left(P(x)+P\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^2 =P(x^2)P\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

If $P'(x)\neq 0$, then $P(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$

$\Rightarrow$  ($a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0+a_n\frac{1}{x^n}+a_{n-1}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}+...+a_1\frac{1}{x}+a_0)^2 = (a_nx^{2n}+a_{n-1}x^{2n-2}+...+a_1x^2+a_0)( a_n\frac{1}{x^{2n}}+a_{n-1}\frac{1}{x^{2(n-1)}}+...+a_1\frac{1}{x^2}+a_0)$

Considering the coefficient of $x^{2n-1}$ we see  : $2a_na_{n-1} = 0$ $\Rightarrow  a_{n-1}= 0$

Considering the coefficient of $x^{2n-3}$ we see  : $2a_na_{n-3}+2a_{n-1}a_{n-2}= 0$
$\Rightarrow  a_{n-3}= 0$

Similarly, we can prove $a_{n-5}=0;a_{n-7}=0;a_{n-9}=0;...$

But at this point I have no further ideas, it is certain that all the coefficients of $P(x)$ cannot simultaneously be zero except $a_n$ (because it is easy to see that $P(x) = Cx^n$ does not satisfy the requirement)

Looking forward to getting help from everyone. Thank you very much! I sincerely apologize for my mistake. I have corrected my post, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Note that $(2P(1))^2=2P(1)$ also has the solution $P(1)=\frac12$

Comment: Are you certain you want $ P(x^2) P(1/x^2)$ on the RHS? If so, your subsequent equations do not agree with it.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I sincerely apologize for my mistake. I have corrected my post, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @CalvinLin help me please !

Comment: @abcccccc. Your equation has the trivial solution $P(x)=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We claim that the only solutions of the equation is $P(x) = 0$.

Let $P(x) = \sum_{k} a_k x^k$ satisfy the given equation. Write $d = \deg P $.

> **Lemma.** $P(x)$ is an even polynomial.
>
> *Proof.* The conclusion is obvious if $P(x)$ is constant, so we only consider the case where $P(x)$ is non-constant.
>
> First, we show that $P(x)$ is either even or odd. Otherwise, there exists a smallest positive odd integer $m$ such that $a_{d-m} \neq 0$. Then by comparing the coefficients of $x^{2d-m}$ in both sides of the equation, we get $ 2a_d a_{d-m} = 0, $, and so, $a_{d-m} = 0$, a contradiction.
>
> Next, by comparing the coefficients of $x^{2d}$ in both sides of the equation, we get $a_d^2 = a_d a_0$, and so, $a_0 = a_d$. This cannot happen if $P(x)$ is odd, and therefore the lemma is proved. $\square$

Now suppose $P(x)$ solves the equation.

- Assume $P(x)$ is non-constant. By the above lemma, $P(x)$ is an even polynomial. In particular, $Q(x) = P(\sqrt{x})$ is still a polynomial in $x$ and satisfies

  $$ (Q(x) + Q(x^{-1}))^2 = (P(x^{1/2} + P(x^{-1/2}))^2 = P(x)P(x^{-1}) = Q(x^2)Q(x^{-2}). $$

  So $Q(x)$ also solves the equation, and in particular, $\deg Q = \frac{1}{2}\deg P$ is also an even integer. Repeating this argument, we find that $\frac{1}{2^k}\deg P$ is an even integer for *all* $k \geq 0$, which is impossible.
- The above contradiction tells that $P(x)$ must be constant. Then by plugging $P(x) = a$ to the equation, we find that $4a^2 = a^2$, and hence $a = 0$. Therefore $P(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$P(x)=0$ is the only solution.

**Proof:**
Let us assume that a non-zero polynomial solution exists. Then it has some degree $n$. Since if $P$ is constant, it is clear that it must be $0$, we'll look at non-constant solutions. So $n\geq 1$.
Now, in the relation you've written above, check the constant term in both polynomials. Equating, we get:
$$2a_n^2+2a_{n-1}^2+...+4a_0^2=a_n^2+a_{n-1}^2+...+a_0^2$$
This means that $a_n=a_{n-1}=...a_0=0$, since sum of square terms is equal to $0$.
Thus, non-zero solution cannot exist.

Comment: Actually the coefficient term in the left-hand side is $2a_n^2 + 2a_{n-1}^2 + \cdots + 2a_1^2 + 4a_0^2$. This makes the proof even easier if $P(x)$ is assumed to be a polynomial with real coefficients. Otherwise, it makes things harder...

Comment: Oh, right. Then all must be $0$ from that step itself. Will edit.